# Group by date and reduce an array to create a new one

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
> source

# =>
[[Fri, 13 Mar 2015, [24.2]],
 [Tue, 17 Mar 2015, [0.01, 8.26]],
 [Mon, 16 Mar 2015, [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]],
 [Mon, 16 Mar 2015, [0.01, 0.01]],
 [Fri, 13 Mar 2015, [24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2]],
 [Fri, 13 Mar 2015, [24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2]],
 [Mon, 16 Mar 2015, [15.95]],
 [Thu, 12 Mar 2015, [352429.0, 35242900.0, 3.0]]
]
```

How can I create this one out of it:

```
[
  [Thu, 12 Mar 2015, aaa]
  [Fri, 13 Mar 2015, bbb],
  [Mon, 16 Mar 2015, ccc],
  [Tue, 17 Mar 2015, ddd]
]
```

Where `aaa`, `bbb` ... are the sums of the elements with the same date. Note that 
  `[Thu, 12 Mar 2015, aaa]`

are 2 elements, not 3: `12 Mar 2015` and `aaa`

What I tried:

```
source.group_by { |x| x[0] }.reduce(0) # sum up all the element except the 1st one which is a date - how?
```

Comment: You need to put all your dates in quotes. I suggest you replace 'aaa', 'bbb', with the actual sums for the example, remove the sentence, "Note that..." and give the data array a name (e.g. `source = [['Fri, 13 Mar 2015', [...`, so those providing answers can reference the array in their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way, perhaps a bit easier to read

```
source.group_by(&:first).map do |k,v|
  [k, v.flat_map(&:last).reduce(:+)]
end
```

Comment: Nice one, Mark. Note you could avoid the need to `flatten` by changing the inner `map` to `flat_map`.

Comment: Excellent catch. Updated. I must say I'm not a huge fan of the way `flat_map` reads (especially in a method chain like the above), but that's what it's there for, so I use it (when I remember :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following.

```
source = [
  ['Fri, 13 Mar 2015', [24.2]],
  ['Tue, 17 Mar 2015', [0.01, 8.26]],
  ['Mon, 16 Mar 2015', [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]], 
  ['Mon, 16 Mar 2015', [0.01, 0.01]],
  ['Fri, 13 Mar 2015', [24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2]], 
  ['Fri, 13 Mar 2015', [24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2,
                        24.2, 24.2, 24.2]], 
  ['Mon, 16 Mar 2015', [15.95]],
  ['Thu, 12 Mar 2015', [352429.0, 35242900.0, 3.0]]
]

source.each_with_object({}) do |(d,a),h|
  h.update(d=>a.reduce(:+)) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end.to_a
  #=> [["Fri, 13 Mar 2015", 435.5999999999999],
  #    ["Tue, 17 Mar 2015", 8.27],
  #    ["Mon, 16 Mar 2015", 16.009999999999998],
  #    ["Thu, 12 Mar 2015", 35595332.0]]
```

If you wish to make this a hash (something to consider), just remove `to_a`:

```
source.each_with_object({}) do |(d,a),h|
  h.update(d=>a.reduce(:+)) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end
  # => {"Fri, 13 Mar 2015"=>435.5999999999999,
  #    ...
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to resolve the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

Comment: what do you use "{ }" for the blocks taking more than one line?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I meant "why". Ruby's convention is to use "do" for multiline blocks.

Comment: Oh, I see. I use `do...end` for multi-statement blocks, but for single statements (like this one), I generally use `{...}`, even if I format the expression to appear on multiple lines. I could have written this on one line, but I thought that would have required you to scroll horizontally to read it (but maybe not), so I wrote it on two lines to make it easier to read.  (I *hate* horizontally scrolling.) If a single expressions is really long, I will use `do...end` 37% of the time.

Comment: You think too much. Just use "do" for multiline expressions because it's the convention.

Comment: Aye, aye, sir (but my fingers may be crossed).

Comment: When I went to bed last night , this was the selected answer and there were two upvotes. This morning it was no longer the selected answer (that happens--@MarkThomas gave a good answer), but the odd thing is that one of the upvotes was retracted and in its place there's a downvote. One might expect that I'd be annoyed, but curiously, there's a wry smile on my face.

Comment: Smiling, but not laughing.

Comment: And I'm the one who's laughing, huh?